# Is this a candidate for javascript Closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I go this code working. But, I've been thinking if this is a candidate for implementing closure. Hear me out.

I want to do this:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {    
    $(this).parents(".heading").next(".list").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("close");
        $(this).parents(".heading").toggleClass("close");
    });

});
```

The problem when the execution is in side `slideToggle` function `this` doesn't seem to point to `trigger`. I found a work around doing this:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {    
    var self = $(this);
    $(this).parents(".heading").next(".list").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        $(self).toggleClass("close");
        $(self).parents(".heading").toggleClass("close");
    });  
});
```

It works. But I am wondering if its a good candidate for implementing closure? And improve code quality, in the process. Thanks.

Comment: what do you think a closure is ?

Comment: Why would `this` point to the clicked element inside another function? Did you read the documentation for `slideToggle` at all? Inside the callback `this` would be the elements that's sliding.

Comment: why wrap ``self`` in ``$()`` again, if ``self`` is already ``$(this)``?

Comment: The second example is however fine (other than the rewrapping^), I don't know how you define a closure, technically you already have one, but you surely don't need another one.

Comment: When you say $(this) inside the slideToggle function, $(this) is referring to what slideToggle is being called on, so in this case that next(".list") which is not what you want. Your work-around is fine or, as answered below, use es6 magic

Answer (score 3):

A closure is not particular useful here, since its goals are different. But you could use the behaviour of arrow functions, which use a lexical context:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {    
    $(this).parents(".heading").next(".list").slideToggle("slow", () => {
        $(this).toggleClass("close");
        $(this).parents(".heading").toggleClass("close");
    });
});
```

Now, `this` will not be altered: arrow functions are ignorant of any context binding and just stick to the lexical context, which means `this` is the same `this` as in the `click` callback function.